# String input and split functions in C

Tags: c, strings, memory-management, pointers

I've some functions targeted to simplify working with strings in some of my other projects. I'd like feedback on this code and whether or not the implementation is **efficient** and **memory safe**. I work with both normal strings (`char*`) and string arrays (`char**`) in this code.

Here's `stringfuncs.c`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "stringfuncs.h"

#define ALLOC_FAIL(ptr, location, alloc_type) \
        if (ptr == NULL) \
        { \
            fprintf(stderr, #alloc_type " failed in " #location); \
            abort(); \
        }

char* str_append(char element, char* str, const int end_index, int* size)
{
    // Inserts a char to given string at given index
    if (end_index == *size)
    {
        // Reallocate if needed
        str = realloc(str, (*size *= 2) * sizeof(*str));
        if (str == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in str_append");
            abort();
        }
    }
    str[end_index] = element;
    return str;
}

char** strarr_append(char* elementstr, char** strarr, const int end_index, int* size)
{
    // Inserts a string to given array at given index
    if (end_index == *size)
    {
        // Reallocate if needed
        strarr = realloc(strarr, (*size *= 2) * sizeof(*strarr));
        if (strarr == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in str_append");
            abort();
        }
    }
    strarr[end_index] = elementstr;
    return strarr;
}

char* trunc_string(char* str, const int end_index)
{
    // Reallocate string for the amount of memory it needs
    str = realloc(str, (end_index + 1) * sizeof(*str));
    // Null terminate the string
    str[end_index] = '\0';
    return str;
}

char** trunc_strarray(char** strarr, const int index)
{
    // Reallocate string array for the amount of memory it needs
    strarr = realloc(strarr, (index + 1) * sizeof(*strarr));
    return strarr;
}

char* get_string(const char* prompt)
{
    // A function to get string user input
    int index, size = 1;
    char element;
    char* string = malloc(size * sizeof(*string));
    ALLOC_FAIL(string, get_string, malloc);
    // Print the given prompt
    printf("%s", prompt);
    for (index = 0; (element = getchar()) != EOF && element != '\n'; index++)
    {
        // Record every character input until user presses enter (and or we encounter EOF)
        string = str_append(element, string, index, &size);
    }
    // Truncate and null terminate the string
    string = trunc_string(string, index);
    return string;
}

char** split_string(const char delimiter, const char* string, int* length)
{
    // Variables to keep track of splitarr
    int arrsize = 2, arrindex = 0;
    // Variables to keep track of elementstr
    int strsize = 2, strindex = 0;
    // Set up splitarr and elementstr with an initial size;
    char** splitarr = malloc(arrsize * sizeof(*splitarr));
    ALLOC_FAIL(splitarr, split_string, malloc);
    char* elementstr = malloc(strsize * sizeof(*elementstr));
    ALLOC_FAIL(elementstr, split_string, malloc);
    for (int index = 0; string[index] != '\0'; strindex++, index++)
    {
        if (string[index] == delimiter)
        {
            // elementstr ends here
            // Truncate and null terminate the string
            elementstr = trunc_string(elementstr, strindex);
            // Add string to string array
            splitarr = strarr_append(elementstr, splitarr, arrindex, &arrsize);
            arrindex++;
            // Cleanup
            strsize = 1;
            strindex = -1;
            elementstr = realloc(NULL, strsize * sizeof(*elementstr));
            ALLOC_FAIL(elementstr, split_string, realloc);
        }
        else
        {
            // non-delimiter character, append to elementstr
            elementstr = str_append(string[index], elementstr, strindex, &strsize);
        }
    }
    // Truncate and null terminate the final string
    elementstr = trunc_string(elementstr, strindex);
    // Add final string to string array
    splitarr = strarr_append(elementstr, splitarr, arrindex, &arrsize);
    // Truncate the string array
    splitarr = trunc_strarray(splitarr, arrindex);
    // Assign the length of the array
    *length = arrindex + 1;
    return splitarr;
}

char** destroy_strarr(char** strarr, int length)
{
    // Free all strings inside an array of strings and the array itself
    int index = 0;
    while (index < length)
    {
        // Free the elements and assign the pointer to NULL
        free(strarr[index]);
        strarr[index++] = NULL;
    }
    // Free the array itself and assign to NULL
    free(strarr);
    strarr = NULL;
    return strarr;
}
```

Here's the corresponding `stringfuncs.h`

```c
#pragma once

/*
Take string input from user
Pass in a string prompt to display to the user prior to input
Returns a pointer to the input string
*/
char* get_string(const char* prompt);

/*
Split given string by delimiter into an array of strings
Pass in the address of a variable to store the length of the array
Returns a pointer to the array of strings
*/
char** split_string(const char delimiter, const char* string, int* length);

/*
Free all the memory used by an array of strings
Assigns all the string elements as NULL
Returns NULL on success
*/
char** destroy_strarr(char** strarr, int length);
```

And example use-

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "stringfuncs.h"

int main()
{
    int length;
    char* input = get_string("> ");
    char** strarr = split_string(' ', input, &length);
    strarr = destroy_strarr(strarr, length);
    free(input);
    input = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Primarily concerned about `split_string` and `get_string`, the rest are helpers.

**Note**: This targets `C` only, not C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> whether or not the implementation is efficient and memory safe.

**memory safe weakness: `int` vs. `size_t`**

With *long* strings, length is limited to `INT_MAX` yet should limit to `SIZE_MAX`.  Recommend `size_t size, end_index`.

**memory safe weakness: `size` extreme range**

Better code would handle `size == 0` and detect when `size * 2` overflows.

```
// str = realloc(str, (*size *= 2) * sizeof(*str));
if (size == 0) size = 2;
else if (size <= SIZE_MAX/2) size *= 2;
else tbd_code();
str = realloc(str, size * sizeof(*str));
```

**Memory efficient strength: allocation**

Good to use exponential allocation growth of size

**Maintenance efficient strength: `sizeof *ptr`**

`sizeof(*strarr)` or `sizeof *strarr` easier to code right, review and maintain than `sizeof (some_type)`

**Functional weakness: `get_string()` and EOF**

When end-of-file (and nothing read), code returns an empty string.  This is indistinguishable from first reading a *null character*.

When a rare input error, there is no indication of a problem.  Code simply forms a string of characters read up to that point.

Perhaps return `NULL` on those cases instead.

**Memory safe strength: destroying `NULL`**

`free()` allows `free(NULL)`.  `destroy_strarr(NULL,0)` is allowed: good.

**Memory safe weakness: missing free strategy**

`stringfuncs.h` should outline what needs to be free'd and how.  Assume user of your good code only sees the .h file.

**General feedback**

- Namespace of functions should be made uniform.  Recommend prefix that matches .h file name.
- `#pragma once` ubiquitous, but not standard C.
- `fprintf(stderr, #alloc_type " failed in " #location)` deserves a `'\n'`.
- I am tempted to put `char *str, size_t end_index, size_t size` in a `struct`.
- `const` in `const char delimiter` of `split_string()` *declaration* serves no purpose.
- Private functions in `stringfuncs.c` should be `static`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate where in the header should I include the free strategy? Should I just include it in the function docstring?

Comment: @Chase Either/Both.

Answer (score 2):

### A note on standards

My suggestions below - around `errno` and `getline` - work off of the POSIX standard, which adds more functionality than the bare C standard. If you are in a Mac or Unix-like environment this will be accessible to you. Other environments like Windows can pull parts of it in depending on which compiler you use.

### errno

This:

```
    if (ptr == NULL) \
    { \
        fprintf(stderr, #alloc_type " failed in " #location); \
```

only offers you partial coverage. The [spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) says that

> Otherwise [when unsuccessful], it shall return a null pointer  and set *errno* to indicate the error.

This means you are better-off calling `perror`. The same applies elsewhere, for example when you check `realloc`.

### Output simplification

Sometimes the compiler will do this for you, but I still find it's a good idea to replace

```
printf("%s", prompt);
```

with

```
puts(prompt);
```

### Getting a line

I think most of `get_string` is unnecessary. Have a read through [`getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Comment: `printf("%s", prompt);` has a different functionality than `puts(prompt);`.  Consider `fputs(prompt, stdout);` instead.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for keeping me honest. Edited.